# Issue with strong typing in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I have the following code:

```
export type FooParams = {
  foo1: { x: number };
  foo2: { y: string };
};

export type FooKey = keyof FooParams; // or export type FooKey = "foo1" | "foo2";

export interface FooAction<T extends FooKey> {
  execute: (params: FooParams[T]) => void;
}

const foo1Action: FooAction<"foo1"> = {
  execute: (params) => {
    console.log(params.x);
  },
};

const foo2Action: FooAction<"foo2"> = {
  execute: (params) => {
    console.log(params.y);
  },
};

export const fooActions: Record<FooKey, FooAction<FooKey>> = {
  foo1: foo1Action,
  foo2: foo2Action,
};
```

I can't strongly type the variable `fooActions`, in order to force a `FooAction` for every `FooKey`. In the above example I have the following error.

```
Type 'FooAction<"foo1">' is not assignable to type 'FooAction<keyof FooParams>'.
  Type 'keyof FooParams' is not assignable to type '"foo1"'.
    Type '"foo2"' is not assignable to type '"foo1"'.ts(2322)
```

Any idea how to correctly declare the `fooActions` type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FooAction<FooKey>` means `execute` will have type `(params: FooParams[FooKey]) => void` which in turns would resolve to `(params: { x: number } | { y: string }) => void;`. This means it will have to be a function that handle both `{ x: number }` and `{ y: number }`. So all values of an object of type `Record<FooKey, FooAction<FooKey>>` would have to handle both types, while `foo1Action` and `foo2Action` can only handle one type or the other.

You want to type `fooActions` with a correlation between the key and the type. You can do that with a custom mapped type:

```
type FooActionMap = {
    [P in FooKey]: FooAction<P>
}
export const fooActions: FooActionMap  = {
  foo1: foo1Action,
  foo2: foo2Action,
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBiEIAUCGUcC2AznALxwDeAUHHAGaYCMAXJXCKwHYCuBARsChwAvgG4a9TACZWFOIlZEYUAJacA5iPFiqVUJFgJkqDBADSwRGTgBrSxDrpMufMVFwA9B7jQ4+6PBIKE7mltYARAwQjOFwAD5wkdLh4nrgAXBqMIJ0OADGJpgAgnkwKhCcADwAKn4g2ZwAJiSmFogAfJQSoMB53NmsABRgeIRErKYuYwDa1QC6AJRknQBuECqN2rp5FUqS0SVlFRPFpeVVSdHhneTUtD19A3DDo8RLpJ13tHA7nEQQABtgAA6AEQdQvVxEYEgBbiWjCAA0VB0VF+eyiUkO5xOEGxFUqlyk12sXwe-WAQxGUPenwktHRgJBYIh1LGwMQcIkSJR4iChTxZwqAFkcGBSfS4NMsJlOCE2nNcfiqlh2ii0gZ4Oj4FFleMQsrReKJbQoix9oxlcjTdJWJirbygA)

Comment: Great explanation. It was quite clear the reason, but I was not aware of that syntax.